# Probability measure of ratio of random variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

Suppose that I have a continuous random variable $X \sim \mu_{X}$ with probability measure $\mu_{X}$ and a discrete random variable $Y \ne 0$ with probability mass function $p_{Y}$. Suppose also that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Consider the random variable $Z$ defined as $$Z=\frac XY$$
how can I express the probability measure of $Z$ (i.e. $\mu_Z$) as a function of $\mu_X$?

Working with cumulative functions is pretty straightforward and I find:
$$ F_Z(t)=\sum_y F_{X}(ty) \: p_{Y}(y)$$
How can I restate this in terms of measures?

Comment: Can you do it for $Z=WX$ where $W$ has a probability mass function? If so, you could try $W=1/Y.$

Comment: If you set $A = (-\infty,t]$, then $\mu_Z(A) = \sum_n\mu_X(nA)p_Y(n)$. This should generalize to all Borel sets $A$.

Comment: Yep, I also ended up with something like this.